# Keras shows shape error at the end of first epoch

Tags: python, keras, lstm, autoencoder

I try to create an LSTM autoencoder with keras

While, it shows a value error at the end of first epoch

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (32,20) (20,20) (32,20)
```

The shape of model input is (sample_size,20,31), and following is the model

The sampling function:

```
def sampling(args):

    z_mean, z_log_var = args
    batch = K.shape(z_mean)[0]
    dim = K.int_shape(z_mean)[1]
    # by default, random_normal has mean=0 and std=1.0
    epsilon = K.random_normal(shape=(batch,dim))
    return z_mean + K.exp(0.5 * z_log_var) * epsilon
```

The encoder part :

```
inputs = Input(shape=(lag,data.shape[1],), name='encoder_input')
x = LSTM(30,activation='relu',return_sequences=True) (inputs)
x = LSTM(60,activation='relu') (x)
z_mean = Dense(60, name='z_mean')(x)
z_log_var = Dense(60, name='z_log_var')(x)
z_temp = Lambda(sampling, output_shape=(60,), name='z')([z_mean, z_log_var])
z = RepeatVector(lag)(z_temp)
encoder = Model(inputs, [z_mean, z_log_var, z], name='encoder')
```

The decoder part :

```
latent_inputs = Input(shape=(lag,60), name='z_sampling')
x_2 = LSTM(60, activation='relu',return_sequences= True)(latent_inputs)
x_2 = LSTM(data.shape[1], activation='relu',return_sequences= True)(x_2)
decoder = Model(latent_inputs, x_2, name='decoder')
outputs = decoder(encoder(inputs)[2])
vae = Model(inputs, outputs)
```

And loss and fit part:

```
outputs = decoder(encoder(inputs)[2])
vae = Model(inputs, outputs)
reconstruction_loss = mse(inputs, outputs)
kl_loss = 1 + z_log_var - K.square(z_mean) - K.exp(z_log_var)
kl_loss = K.mean(kl_loss)
kl_loss *= -0.1
vae_loss = reconstruction_loss + kl_loss
vae.add_loss(vae_loss) 
vae.compile(optimizer='adam')
vae.fit(train,epochs=100)
```

It will cause this error :

```
Epoch 1/100
632256/632276 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0372
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (32,20) (20,20) (32,20)
```

If there is a shape error, how dose model work at previous step. That's my main problem, thanks for your answer

Comment: Could you provide reproducible code? How do you define `sampling`?

Comment: Is this the complete error message? I see no Op and Tensor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are working with batch size of **32**, but at the very end your operand get a tensor with only **20** elements, because this amount remains after 632256 from 632276:

```
632276 - 632256 = 20
```

Basically this is the error message about and that is why the previous steps worked.

**Most straightforward solution:**

use [fit()](https://keras.io/models/sequential/#fit) method's `steps_per_epoch` option:

> **steps_per_epoch:** Integer or None.
> Total number of steps (batches of
> samples) before declaring one epoch finished and starting the next
> epoch. When training with input tensors such as TensorFlow data
> tensors, the default None is equal to the number of samples in your
> dataset divided by the batch size, or 1 if that cannot be determined.

```
steps_per_epoch = total_samples // batch_size
```

In this case basically you drop the last 20 samples.

Comment: Oh, it works. I drop the last 20 samples manually. But I can't understand why this happen. In my opinion, fit() function will detect batch_size itself. Why there is remainder this time. Still thank you.

Comment: @JackyTsai Actually `fit()` does "detect" `batchsize` but does not check it e.g. keras `make_batches` make batches like this from batchsize=32, number of samples=74: [(0, 32), (32, 64), (64, 74)].

Comment: Your code won't work. `np.ceil(33/32)` gets `2.0`. It does not drop the 1 nor gives an `int`. Tried `total_samples//batch_size` which is correct. This time it fails at the beginning of 2nd epoch. 34240/34247 [====>.] xxxx Epoch 2/15
   71/34247 [....] ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (7,) (64,) (7,)

Comment: @MeowCat2012 I don't really know, why I used ceil as in practice I always use //. So thanks for the catch. Regarding the value error, it is due some other issue.